# Sets in a ring that are subset of another set in the ring

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a ring $R$ and $r \in R$ with the property that $\lambda(r)<\infty$. Where $\lambda$ is a $\sigma$-finite pre-measure. Why do we find $Y \in \sigma(R)$ so that $ Y \subset r$ is true?

Comment: Do you mean $Y\in\sigma(R)$ such that $Y\subseteq r$, where $\sigma(R) $ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $R$? If so, what about $Y:=r$?

Comment: Okay, thank you I didn't see that. I copied exactly the assumptions my lecturer gave, so far as explanation of the mistaken $\subset$. In case of further questions I'm going to give a signal.